Node.js Express app not rendering HTML file; only shows a blank page
Body: I am developing a simple Node.js application using Express. My goal is to serve an HTML file located in the views folder, but when I access the page, it shows a blank screen without any content.
Code:
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});


HTML File (views/index.html):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>This is a test page.</p>
</body>
</html>


Error Messages: I do not see any error messages in the terminal or the browser console.
What I've Tried:
I ensured that the server is running and that I can access http://localhost:3000/.
I checked the file paths to ensure they are correct.
I tried using a simple HTML file to see if it renders anything.
I am using Windows 10 (Crack Version) and wondering if it might affect the application.
Expected vs. Actual Behavior:
Expected: The browser should display "Hello World!" and the text "This is a test page."
Actual: The page is blank with no content displayed.
Environment:
OS: Windows 10 (Crack Version)
Node.js version: 20.17.0
Express version: 4.21.1

The problem is not reproducible. If you did everything as described, html file will be served. "I ensured that the server is running and that I can access" - how do you know that?

when you run the JS code, is the html page shown?

Yes. It's expected to. The example is very simple and straightforward, there's no room for mistake

I can confirm the server is running because I see the message Example app listening on port 3000.
When I access http://localhost:3000/, the browser shows a blank page, even though I’ve written contents into index.html and saved them.
I've verified the file path and ensured the HTML structure is correct.

then what do you think, what problem it can be? Can it be a problem in my OS

You need to check what's server response in browser devtools, eliminating a layer of uncertainty this way. In case of any problem you should see an error, either in a console or server response

Can you guide me how to do this? if you can, as much as possible. Tell me the process what to do step by step, if you can. I would be thankful to you!

It's unknown what's your browser, and it's not easy to guide for basic things without looking. I'd suggest to check the basics on how to debug network requests in a browser. You can start with browser's own docs, e.g. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network for chorme-based. You need to check status and body of a response for http://localhost:3000/ request. I'd suggest to try more than one browser, in case there's a problem on your side. Also try to access through http://127.0.0.1:3000 instead of localhost and also try another port. But there should've been errors already for that

Make sure you're using http:// and not https:// , but again, for any such mistake you should've already seen errors that could suggest what you do wrong

I used postman in addition to chrome. But in postman, it's all same. Now, i need to be sure, is the code correctly functionable. If you can, run the code exactly like mine. and see does it work. It should work, very simple code.Dont know why this problem is happening.

i asked chat gpt. is says,it can also be  because of my cracked windows 10. Does it happen really

Might I suggest you add a console.log() call in your code to double check the path to your html file is correct. i.e.      console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'index.html'));

ok, i am trying

" it's all same" - how exactly? What is the response in postman? Please, update the question. There's no mistake in code, and there's no room for it. If there's an error, it should appear either in a console where you run node process and/or in the response. I.e. if it fails to set up the server because 3000 is occupied, there will be an error, and if there's no html file at that location, there will be a respective error too. And even if "localhost" is messed up in "hosts" file, there will be an error in a browser because there's no server  running at 3000.

There's always can problems that are caused by OS, but I'm unaware of such conditions for what you describe. It's more likely that the whole networking to be affected rather than specific requests, especially local ones. But if you have some vpn, try to disable it. You need to try multiple clients, but postman+regular browser may be enough in this regard.  And you need to check that localhost works the same as 127.0.0.1 at least. And consider using @ to address other users in your question if you want them to receive notifications

Because of the recent updates you have to use the ES6 module of Node which involves you using the import format but before this, you have to run 

~npm I express on your terminal

In your package.json folder after "name": my-project, "description": "simple-app", etc add this to it  "type": "module", 

your folder hierarchy should follow this format
my-project/
├── node_modules/
├── public/
│   └── css/
|   |   └── input.css
├── views/
│   └── index.ejs
├── index.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json 

Your code should javascript look like this 

import express from "express";

const app = express();
const port = 3030;

app.use(express.static("node_modules"));
app.set('view-engine', 'ejs');
app.use( express.static("public"));  

app.get("/" , (req,res) =>{
 res.render("index.ejs");
});

app.listen( port , ()=> {
  console.log(`App is listening at port ${port}`);
  });


rename your index.html to index.ejs

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link href="/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>This is a test page.</p>
</body>
</html> 

